# How to parallel computing in case the input is a matrix?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I have a dataframe `df_simulate` containing 1000 rows and 10001 columns. I define a function `var_sum` that takes a pair of integers `(m, n)` as input and returns a real value.

My laptop has 6 cores and 12 logical processors. I want to do parallel computing to speed up the process. Because the function `clusterApply` requires a vector as an input, I'm stuck at applying it to my case, which is a matrix. Could you please elaborate on how to achieve my goal?

```
require("parallel")
require("snow")
library("parallel")
detectCores(logical = FALSE) # number of cores
detectCores() # number of logical cores or threads

n_simu <- 1000
set.seed(1)
df_simulate <- data.frame(x_1 = rnorm(n_simu))
for (k in 2:10000) {
set.seed(k)
df_simulate[, paste0("x_", k)] <- rnorm(n_simu)
}
df_simulate[, "y"] <- runif(n_simu, 0, 0.5)
df_simulate[df_simulate$x_40 > 0 & df_simulate$x_99 > 0.8, "y"] <-
df_simulate[df_simulate$x_40 > 0 & df_simulate$x_99 > 0.8, "y"] + 5.75
df_simulate[df_simulate$x_40 > 0 & df_simulate$x_99 <= 0.8 & df_simulate$x_30 > 0.5, "y"] <-
df_simulate[df_simulate$x_40 > 0 & df_simulate$x_99 <= 0.8 & df_simulate$x_30 > 0.5, "y"] + 18.95
df_simulate[df_simulate$x_40 > 0 & df_simulate$x_99 <= 0.8 & df_simulate$x_30 <= 0.5, "y"] <-
df_simulate[df_simulate$x_40 > 0 & df_simulate$x_99 <= 0.8 & df_simulate$x_30 <= 0.5, "y"] + 20.55
df_simulate[df_simulate$x_40 <= 0 & df_simulate$x_150 < 0.5, "y"] <-
df_simulate[df_simulate$x_40 <= 0 & df_simulate$x_150 < 0.5, "y"] - 5
df_simulate[df_simulate$x_40 <= 0 & df_simulate$x_150 >= 0.5, "y"] <-
df_simulate[df_simulate$x_40 <= 0 & df_simulate$x_150 >= 0.5, "y"] - 10

### Function to calculate the sum of variances
sum_var <- function(n, m){
  df1 <- sort(df_simulate[, m])
  index <- (df1 <= df_simulate[[n, m]])
  df2 <- df1[index]
  df3 <- df1[! index]
  return(sd(df2) + sd(df3))
}
```

Comment: So you want to apply your function over all rows and columns? In R you would use `mapply` for this, so you could try `future_mapply` from the [future.apply](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future.apply) package. If you use a UNIX system, you could also try `mcmapply` from the parallel package

Comment: @starja I want to apply it not on rows and columns itself, but on the indices of them. You can see this from the fact that my function takes a pair of integers `(m, n)` as input. The use of the dataframe is already encoded inside the function. It seems to me that `future_mapply` does not have the option for the number of threads in parallel process.

Comment: sorry, yes I mean every row/column index. Check out the vignettes for `future.apply`, it uses the `future` package as the backend where you can specify the parallelisation options

Comment: also, you could check if modifying your code so that not always the complete `df_simulate` but only the selected column `m` is passed to the workers is beneficial (then not the complete data.frame has to be copied all the time)

Comment: @starja In my function, there are 2 places where `df_simulate` is called, i.e. `df1 <- sort(df_simulate[, m])` and `index <- (df1 <= df_simulate[[n, m]])`. It seems to me that only the column `df_simulate[, m]` and the cell `df_simulate[[n, m]])` are called. I'm not sure if this is as you suggested.

Comment: exactly, you only need the data from column `m`. So you could try to parallelise over the columns and then in every parallel process calculate the results serially for every row `n`. You can try if this has advantages compared to parallelise over columns and rows, because the parallelisation generates some overhead

Comment: @starja your suggestion is exactly the way my professor solves the problem. I'm surprised for that. Thank you so much for your elaboration.